# Ejabberd and Python3

Tags: xml, python-3.x, ejabberd

Getting syntax error while trying to connect ejabberd with python package pyejabberd.

Bellow is the error-

`<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream id='12042217178057076392' version='1.0' xml:lang='en' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client'><stream:error><not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/><text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'>syntax error</text></stream:error></stream:stream>`

Code :

```
from pyejabberd import EjabberdAPIClient

client = EjabberdAPIClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=5222,
                       username='admin@arojit.com', password='arojit',
                       user_domain='arojit.com',
                       protocol='http')

try:
    registered_users = client.registered_users('arojit.com')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the username should be 'admin', not 'admin@arojit.com'.